# VBA code to track changes

Tags: vba, excel

I Need a VBA code which can track the changes with OLD sheet & NEW sheet with the values not by Cells,we have a Unique value which will be same in both sheets is in "Z"column.

If any new no.will be found, it should Highlight as a new Order No.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdXvA.png) is the sheet screenshot in that Z column contains the Unique no.with which i tried to compare with old sheet,but i failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do what you expect:

```
Sub foo()
Dim wsNew As Worksheet: Set wsNew = Sheets("NEW")
Dim wsOld As Worksheet: Set wsOld = Sheets("OLD")
'above declare and set both your worksheets, amend as required
Dim Result As String

OldLastRow = wsOld.Cells(wsOld.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
NewLastRow = wsNew.Cells(wsNew.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
'above get the number of rows with data on each sheet on column Z

For i = 2 To NewLastRow 'loop through New sheet from row 2 to last
    SearchValue = wsNew.Cells(i, "Z") 'get the value of that row
    For x = 2 To OldLastRow 'loop through Old sheet to find a match
        If wsOld.Cells(x, "Z") = SearchValue Then Result = "Found" 'if match found, set Result variable as flag
    Next x
    If Result = "Found" Then 'if found
        Result = "" 'remove flag before next loop
    Else 'if not found
        wsNew.Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274 'highlight the row
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If instead of highlighting the row, you wish to copy that row to another sheet then the following will copy the row to Sheet4, amend the sheet name as required:

```
Sub foo()
Dim wsNew As Worksheet: Set wsNew = Sheets("NEW")
Dim wsOld As Worksheet: Set wsOld = Sheets("OLD")
Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("Sheet4")
'above declare and set both your worksheets, amend as required
Dim Result As String
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

OldLastRow = wsOld.Cells(wsOld.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
NewLastRow = wsNew.Cells(wsNew.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
'above get the number of rows with data on each sheet on column Z

For i = 2 To NewLastRow 'loop through New sheet from row 2 to last
    SearchValue = wsNew.Cells(i, "Z") 'get the value of that row
    For x = 2 To OldLastRow 'loop through Old sheet to find a match
        If wsOld.Cells(x, "Z") = SearchValue Then Result = "Found" 'if match found, set Result variable as flag
    Next x
    If Result = "Found" Then 'if found
        Result = "" 'remove flag before next loop
    Else 'if not found
        NextFreeRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsNew.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsResult.Cells(NextFreeRow, 1)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code sir,but please guide me where will i get the results

Answer (score 0):

Please check the attachment,here in this workbook,sheet OLD contains old data & NEW contains NEW updated data,actually I need to track the changes wherever its done,for that I tried to concatenated the columns "B" & "F" in column "Z" to get the unique no.s so with that reference i can find the it in OLD sheet & if found then copy both entire rows from both sheets(NEW & OLD) & then track the changes by cells,but it not working. Because sometimes changes are happening in "N" i.e Required QTY,so i am not able track them.& IF NEW row will be added in NEW sheet then it will appear as new order.

For this I tried to copy the match founded rows on different sheets & not founded rows also & then tried with track changes by comparing cells,but i failed,can you please suggest me something better.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIf0j.png)enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q49Oh.png)

Comment: your original question asked to highlight the row, then you asked to copy the row to another sheet, I've updated my answer to reflect these, now I'm not too sure how you would like to track changes, but it might be best to ask a new question. (Also when you want to add more information to your question, you should edit it instead of adding answers to it)